# Linux Splitting/duplicating X11 server

Tags: linux, x11, vnc, system-administration, vnc-server

(ubuntu 19.10)

Hello,

I was wondering if it's possible to split what's output to a Linux x11 server and duplicate it onto a VNC server.

Basically I currently have a Java Application (prebuilt JAR so I don't have much control over it) that renders something to the native X11 server in: /tmp/.X11-unix. What I want to do is duplicate the information that's being written to the X11 socket to also be written to a VNC server at the same time.

**Currently**:
    Running Java GUI Application --*producesData*--> Data --*isWrittenTo*--> /tmp/.X11-unix

**Desired:**
    Running Java GUI Application --*producesData*--> Data --*isWrittenTo*--> /tmp/.X11-unix **AND** --isWrittenTo--> /tmp/vnc-server

**Other (less desired) solution:**
Running Java GUI Application --*producesData*--> Data --*isWrittenTo*--> /tmp/.X11-unix --*isCopiedTo*--> /tmp/vnc-server  (not sure if there's even a difference between just running a normal VNC server)

If possible I'd rather not copy the entire X11 server's content (the whole desktop), but just what's being delivered by the Java Application. If this isn't possible what's the next best solution?

Thanks

Comment: You might consider using [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb). Your question is not a programming question (but a sysadmin one) so is off-topice here.

Comment: Looks like  good starting poitn for further exploration, thanks